# Cant download artifact from nexus because of invalid rsa public key

Tags: java, rsa, nexus

I am trying to download artifact from our local nexus with gradle but I am getting  some errors

This is the error log :

`org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: java.io.IOException: subject key, java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA public key`

our nexus is not configure on https so why I am getting ssl errors?

Answer (score 1):

you might be using a client certificate that doesn't match your nexus's server certificate.

Comment: how I can check it? where is my client certificate locate ?